# osquery - warnings when using osqueryi and logging disabled

Tags: osquery

When using the `osqueryi` interactive shell for [osquery](https://osquery.io) I'm running into an issue where a WARNING is displayed even though logging is supposed to be disabled. Is this a bug?

[Docs](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/cli-flags/) explain the following:

`--logger_min_status`

> > The minimum level for status log recording. Use the following values: INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, ERROR = 2. To disable all status messages use 3+.

`--logger_min_sterr`

> > The minimum level for status logs written to stderr. Use the following values: INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, ERROR = 2. To disable all status messages use 3+.

#### What I have: (results truncated for brevity)

```
# osqueryi --json --logger_min_status=3 --logger_min_stderr=3 'select * from block_devices'

WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
[{"block_size":"512","label":"","model":"VBOX HARDDISK","name":"/dev/sda","parent":"","size":"83886080","type":"","uuid":"","vendor":"ATA"},...]
```

#### What I expect:

```
# osqueryi --json --logger_min_status=3 --logger_min_stderr=3 'select * from block_devices'

[{"block_size":"512","label":"","model":"VBOX HARDDISK","name":"/dev/sda","parent":"","size":"83886080","type":"","uuid":"","vendor":"ATA"},...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This logging seems to be coming from the LVM library, so is likely not controllable by osquery. I couldn't find the exact log line in the LVM2 source.

I believe it is the [populatePVChildren](https://github.com/facebook/osquery/blob/experimental/osquery/tables/system/linux/block_devices.cpp#L29-L62) function that would be calling an LVM function that performs the logging.

Your interpretation of the documentation around debugging looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. That's unfortunate, I suppose I'll have to trim the warning.